# terraform 'condition' error in google_project_iam_binding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm try create user and set a policy to him.
Create user, is ok.
The problem is when I try set a condition.

Via gcloud works fine, but using terraform, not.
When I remove the condition line, works, but I need this condition.

Follow the gcloud command:

```
cloud projects add-iam-policy-binding projeto-xyz --member='serviceAccount:client-bot@projeto-xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/storage.objectAdmin' --condition='expression=resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Bucket" && resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/bucket-clientz") ,title=bucket'
```

Follow, the iam.tf:

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = var.accountid
  display_name = var.iam-display-name
   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${var.accountid}.json --iam-account ${var.accountid}@${var.project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
  members  = [
    "serviceAccount:${var.accountid}@${var.project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
  condition {
    title       = "bucket"
    description = "acessar_bucket"
    expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\"&& resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket")"
  }
}
```

Error output:

```
$terraform plan
```

Error: Missing newline after argument

```
  on iam.tf line 18, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project":
  18:     expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\"&& resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket")"

An argument definition must end with a newline.


Error: Invalid character

  on iam.tf line 18, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project":
  18:     expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\"&& resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket")"
```

This character is not used within the language.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using google-beta as provider in the resource, the error messages
about 'condition' has gone and. Now I can create service account and use role with condition to this account.

Thanks, John Hanley, for the support.

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {

  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)

  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}
provider "google-beta" {

  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)

  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
```

iam.tf:

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  provider = google-beta
  account_id   = var.accountid
  display_name = var.iam-display-name 
   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${var.accountid}.json --iam-account ${var.accountid}@${var.project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

}
resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
  provider = google-beta
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
  member  =  "serviceAccount:${var.accountid}@${var.project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  condition {
   title       = "bucket"
   description = "acessar_bucket"
   expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket}\")"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not escape all quotes in the condition. When you see the error `Missing newline after argument` this often means an unescaped quote has ended a string and the following text is unexpected.

Change this line:

```
expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\"&& resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket")"
```

To this:

```
expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket}\")"
```

Comment: More error after change.: Error: Invalid character

  on iam.tf line 18, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project":
  18:     expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/${var.gcp-bucket\")"
....

Comment: when I remove "&& ...." and left "resource.type..." other error: Error: Unsupported block type

  on iam.tf line 15, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project":
  15:   condition {

Blocks of type "condition" are not expected here.

Comment: @LuciannoRamalho - I noticed another syntax error in your code. I updated the `To this` line.

Comment: Note: Be careful using `google_project_iam_binding`. This will replace bindings which means you can lock yourself out of your project. Instead use `google_project_iam_member` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_member

Comment: Error: Unsupported block type

  on iam.tf line 15, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project":
  15:   condition {

Blocks of type "condition" are not expected here.

Comment: @LuciannoRamalho - Execute `terraform init -upgrade` What versions are displayed? Are you using an old provider?

Comment: I think is updated... $ terraform init --upgrade

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google-beta...
- Finding hashicorp/google versions matching "3.5.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.0.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.0.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/google-beta v3.51.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google-beta v3.51.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/google v3.5.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v3.5.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Comment: Were you using an old Google provider? If yes, what was the old version? Does it work now?

Comment: This didn't work for me till I removed `projets/_/buckets/` and just put in the just the bucket name prefix, 
`expression  = "resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"${var.gcp-bucket}\")"`