# Terraform: "Wrong number of parts to Binding id" error message when attempting to import user-role bind

Tags: google-cloud-platform, binding, terraform, roles

I'm using Terraform with module `google_project_iam_binding` to declare an already existing resource in the Terraform file, which has resources that have been declared and imported previously (but not with that module).

After being declared, `terraform plan -out my-terraform-project.plan` is executed, and no issues are found (stating that the resource will be created). However, if I try to import the resource with `terraform import google_project_iam_binding.log-writer my-terraform-project`, I get: `Error: Wrong number of parts to Binding id [feltboard-dev-devops]; expected 'resource_name role [condition_title]'.`

This is what I have in the terraform file:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log-writer" {
  project             = "my-terraform-project"
  role                = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  members             = [
    "serviceAccount:log-writer-account@my-terraform-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}
```

And the log file shows this:

```
2021/07/09 14:32:33 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalImportState, err: Wrong number of parts to Binding id [my-terraform-project]; expected 'resource_name role [condition_title]'.

2021/07/09 14:32:33 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Wrong number of parts to Binding id [my-terraform-project]; expected 'resource_name role [condition_title]'.
```

The service account exists, has been already declared in the terraform file and imported. I tried with module `google_project_iam_binding`, but got the same results. I do not notice anything remarkably different from the example in the [related terraform doc page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding). I also tried including the `condition {...` part in the example but still can't import the resource. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [terraform 'condition' error in google\_project\_iam\_binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533502/terraform-condition-error-in-google-project-iam-binding)

Answer (score 1):

The import command was incomplete. It should have been

```
terraform import google_project_iam_binding.log-writer "my-terraform-project roles/logging.logWriter"
```